# How to remove specific number in string that is in random order?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say that I have data rows that look like this:

```
+----------------------------+
+   test_table               +
+----+--------+--------------+
+ id + word   + updated_word +
+----+--------+--------------+
+ 1  + g00gle + ggle         +
+ 2  + bread0 + bread        +
+ 3  + 0bject + bject        +
+ 4  + d0d0   + dd           +
+-------------+--------------+
```

What statement could I use to take out the zeroes in the word column, so that it looks like the updated_word column? I thought of using substring, but didn't know how to proceed after that.

Comment: Try to use replace method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
UPDATE test_table 
SET word = REPLACE(word, '0', '');
```

replace the 2nd blank '' with anything you want to change with.